# Story where someone had the power to lower someone's temperature by several degrees

Tags: story-identification, powers

One of those things nagging at the edge of my head this morning. Somewhere in the last decade, I was reading a bit of superpower fiction where I think they were discussing seemingly useless powers that were actually very effective, and one of the examples they gave was a person (female, I think), who could lower the temperature of something she touched by a relatively small amount, like 5 degrees Fahrenheit, and someone pointing out that it meant she could inflict instant hypothermia on a subject, making their body start to shut down. I think it was written fiction, online, not certain if it was fanfiction or original. My gut feeling is that it was longer than a short story, maybe part of a chapter of a longer work like a book. I don't *think* it was a webcomic, but my brain could be betraying me.

Comment: This is probably not the source material that you remember, but in 1982 Saturday Night Live ran a skit about four pathetic superheroes, called "The Interesting Four". Julia Louise Dreyfus portrayed 'Weather Woman', a heroine who could raise or lower the temperature by a minor amount.

Comment: In [A Sh*tload of Crazy Powers](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/58108143) by Jackson Ford the character Chloe can raise or lower temperature by a few degrees, and she does indeed use it to cause hypothermia. However I don't recall any discussion of useless superpowers.